# How can French University (Master Coordinator) approve full-time internship that overlaps with classes for M1 student

Tags: ethics, university, internship, france

I'm Currently a non-EU holding a Master degree in Physics and accumulating almost 2ys. of work experience. Getting closer to the EU market is hard; I was "brought" to France via a scholarship to study C.S. in a Master M1.

After receiving several internship offers, many of them to start asap, I noticed that all this great projects require the signature from the Master Coordinators.

Naturally, I've heard that the two coordinators appear to be reluctant to sign a contract that asks the student to participate in full-time projects, as formally he/she should supposedly be attending to class. The nature of this classes is 2hs per day, 4 days a week, and assistance is no taken into account so the courses can be passed by only attending to the final examination.

Relationship with Master coordinators appears to be good or at least normal. One of them was an active promoter of this scholarship, which somehow made them won my attention over other top EU Univs. The other is a sincere Jr. Researcher that does not answer any of the students emails, but in person is very polite and has attention to detail, and has more paperwork-experience than his colleague. I understand that in the capital of France the Universities are being 're-organized' and being Master Coordinators may be a valuable asset in their career.

They probably don't know it, but the economical situation in my country/family does not permit me to pursue what in France is called "M2", the second part of the program. Waiting one year more to be able to take full-time internships is to me unacceptable. I should produce money and send it back asap. Of course they might not need this information, so I haven't actively booked an appointment to tell them. In order to reach a stable regime of being employed full-time as soon as possible, I can see two paths.

(1) keep the smooth sailing until one of my applications to a full-time job requiring work-visa sponsorship succeeds, which has a probability unknown. Once that happens, proceed to (2) and tell the coordinators.

(2) sitting down with the Master Coordinators to have an honest talk.

The purpose of this question is to analyze the latter, and potentially save us all an awkward and unproductive moment. French Academy's bureaucracy seems at times very disorganized, but I shouldn't want to make a mistake when I conclude from that that it's probably also very flexible.

As I mentioned earlier, French internships require University Agreements, and I already have several offers that overlap to different extents with future courses. Regarding the honest talk, I should sit down with at least one of them (which? perhaps both), and explain (without any mention to personal issues, e.g. home-country, family situation) that I would like to participate in a full-time internship starting right now. I should explicitly mention that I will be able to pass the program while only going to the exams, thus they have my full commitment to pass the program and thus not affect their rating as Master Coordinators. They even may have thought until that moment that I'm a potential PhD candidate. Of course it would be to me an honour stop collecting the scholarship and live under the internship stipend, or even 'donating it to their department' if required.

I do have an asset to gift them. The Jr. Researcher + paperwork expert seems to be a low-frequency lonely publisher, but his colleague is very motivated and obviously could use more students working for him. His line is quite theoretical. As I have part-time experience in participating in research lines that lead to publications in peer-reviewed-journals, and even have plans for that during 2022, I have not yet informed him my intention to devote myself part-time to tackling one of his many ideas. This is in parallel with the program, 'for free', out of sole gratitude for having connected me with the scholarship. PhD candidates should be very lucky to have him as director. This is information he does not have and maybe could be put on the table, unconditionally, during the same discussion.

I do not understand the nature of their mandate as Master Coordinators, thus I don't understand to what extent my different verbal probes could insult them and/or the institution, but without further information I should default to (1) and do not produce them further inconvenience. A point of view from someone in an equivalent position, preferably in France, could be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: What you are proposing is in essence (even though it might not be legally speaking) a form of immigration fraud, a way to be allowed to work in France under false pretenses.  Many people would consider it unethical.  Personally I would consider it, but I think most immigration laws are themselves unethical.

Comment: I *feel* you are thinking way too much about all this, just ask them if it is possible? To me it seems like a simple question and there might be already regulations on this which the master coordinators should be able to answer.